# Change content of UITableView on segmentedControl changed index

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've tried several things which i've found on stackoverflow, but wont change the content of the tableView when segmentedIndex is changed. What am i doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    //Do something
    [self.theTableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[GroupCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: @"cell"];
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {




            cell.team = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 50, 50)];

            cell.team.text = @"team1";
            cell.team.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
            cell.team.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.team];



            cell.team = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 50, 50)];

            cell.position.text = @"1";
            cell.position.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
            cell.position.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.position];


    } else {

        cell.team.text = @"team2";
        cell.team.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.team.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.team];
    }



    }
    return cell;

}
```

ViewDidLoad segmentedControl :

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Groups", @"Fixtures", nil]];



segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(-3, 0, self.view.frame.size.width+6, 40);
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

segmentedControl.tintColor =
 [UIColor colorWithRed: 13 / 255.0f
                 green: 78 / 255.0f
                  blue: 102 / 255.0f
                 alpha: 1.0f];



[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: Your code only runs if cell==nil. So changing the `UISegmentedControl` will not change the contents of the already loaded (dequeued) cells.

Comment: If you have a custom cell class, why isn't it responsible for setting up its own subviews? The view controller shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its missing from your code, or you just forgot to copy it on your question, but since you are creating the segmentControl from code, you added this somewhere, right?

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(segmentControlValueChanged:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your cell when there is no available cell from the queue, and then change the values of the cell. Something like:

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    //Do something
    [self.theTableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Try to get an already initialized cell from the queue
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) { //No Cell found, create one
        cell = [[GroupCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.team = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 50, 50)];
        cell.position = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 50, 50)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.team];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.position];
    }

    //Now let's fill the values in our (initialized) cell
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        cell.team.text = @"team1";
        cell.team.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.team.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.position.text = @"1";
        cell.position.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.position.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {
        cell.team.text = @"team2";
        cell.team.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.team.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when i press change the segmentedIndex have added more information in question